# Laravel, modify relation result

Tags: collections, laravel, model, eloquent

is it possible to modify/manipulate the Collection result from a Relation directly in model.

I have a Attachments model, this have many Parent models (News, Events, Pages, User...), and i would  like return a Collection with 3 sub Collections.

Request:

```
$attachments = News::find(1)->attachments()->get();
```

Result:

```
Collection =>
   Collection => (Image, Image, ...),
   Collection => (Word, ...),
   Collection => (Video, ...)
```

I could filter that in Controller, but is it possible to modify the result collection in model?

Comment: Can you show us what structure you would get from `News::find(1)->attachments()->get();` currently?

Comment: One way you could do that is to create a public function in a model that would get your relation and manipulate it there. Than return resulting your collections. This way you would at least keep your controller clean.

Comment: You can do whatever you like, but you might not be able to rely on dynamic properties and stuff like that. Specify what you need exactly.